# I want to immediately execute things when TAB loads another ViewController

Tags: ios, xcode, tabbar

I followed a storyboard tutorial and used IB to make an iPhone app with a Tab Bar Controller connected to 3 Navigation Controllers called Home, Scripts, and Settings.  Home is first, so, at the start, viewDidLoad does its thing.  Then TAB to Scripts or Settings and do other stuff.  On TAB Home, I'd like the app to immediate make some changes, perhaps based on changes in the other TABs.  Someone posted that viewWillAppear will execute with a TAB, but not so.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear {
    NSLog(@"Back Home.\n");
}
```

This never executes on TAB Home.  Please tell me I'm missing something simple.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you use the right method signature:

`- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated`

Try implementing your method this way:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL) animated {
    [super viewWillAppear: animated];
    NSLog(@"Back Home.\n");
}
```

Comment: Yep, I'm dumb. That fixed it.  Thank you!